# Debugging Android Browser App

Tags: cordova, remote-debugging, android-browser

I'm trying to debug my PhoneGap app in android, but with devices that have the factory installed browser app for Android instead of chrome I can't use Chrome inspect to test them.

Is there an alternative solution to solving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ripple emulator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ripple-emulator) to debug your app with browser's inspect element and can able to run your app with different devices.